# How to get the data from a html table with multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table

I have a page containing this table which comes from a PHP script.

[image]

What I want to to do? I want to fetch every value inside these 4 inputs, separately and save them inside 4 Javascript variables. I already have the `onclick="fetchGrades();` on every button.

How can I achieve this? It's the **last** thing I need to do on this project.

Also, I'm using all these technologies: PHP, MySQL, jQuery, Bootstrap, AJAX

**As requested, the HTML of the current table:**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>61</th>
        <th>1º </th>
        <th>2º </th>
        <th>3º </th>
        <th>4º </th>
        <th> Botão </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Patrick Maia</td>
            <td><input id="e12467" type="text"> </td>
            <td><input id="e12467" type="text"> </td>
            <td><input id="e12467" type="text"> </td>
            <td><input id="e12467" type="text"> </td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="fetchGrades();"> Adicionar </button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Rodrigo Marques</td>
            <td><input id="46c9ac" type="text"> </td>
            <td><input id="46c9ac" type="text"> </td>
            <td><input id="46c9ac" type="text"> </td>
            <td><input id="46c9ac" type="text"> </td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="fetchGrades();"> Adicionar </button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**The ID's inside every input comes from a field on the MySQL they come from.**

Comment: Can you show the html for one of the rows ...

Comment: I can't work without code, can you? *Didn't think so*. ;)

Comment: Maybe try looking up how to fetch the value from an input using jQuery or vanilla JS, that should pretty much solve your problem.

Comment: IDs cannot match ... there can be ONLY ONE.

Comment: What if i add _1, _2, _3, _4 on every id on each row? That would make them unique.

Comment: You should use `field[$id_here]` for their name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your inputs in your HTML table were organized something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            61
        </th>
        <th>
            1
        </th>
        <th>
            2
        </th>
        <th>
            3
        </th>
        <th>
            4
        </th>
        <th>
            Boton
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Patrick Maia
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="tblData_Row_1" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="tblData_Row_1" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="tblData_Row_1" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="tblData_Row_1" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Accionar" onclick="fetchGrades('tblData_Row_1');" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Rodrigo Marquez
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="tblData_Row_2" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="tblData_Row_2" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="tblData_Row_2" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="tblData_Row_2" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Accionar" onclick="fetchGrades('tblData_Row_2');" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You could easily use JQuery to handle the rest:

```
function fetchGrades(rowClass) {
    var JSONresults = {};

    var indexColumn = 0;

    $('.' + rowClass).each(function () {
        indexColumn++;
        JSONresults['field_' + indexColumn] = $(this).val();
    });

    alert(JSON.stringify(JSONresults)); //show me my JSON object in string format
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this ...

```
function fetchGrades() {
  var first = document.getElementById('FirstField_row1').value;
  var second = document.getElementById('SecondField_row1').value;
  var third = document.getElementById('ThirdField_row1').value;
  var fourth = document.getElementById('FourthField_row1').value;
}
```

**WITH jQuery**:

```
function fetchGrades() {
  var first = $('#FirstField_row1').val();
  var second = $('#SecondField_row1').val();
  var third = $('#ThirdField_row1').val();
  var fourth = $('#FourthField_row1').val();
}
```

**ASSUMES**:

```
<td><input id='FirstField_row1'/></td>
<td><input id='SecondField_row1'/></td>
<td><input id='ThirdField_row1'/></td>
<td><input id='FourthField_row1'/></td>
```

Comment: But the number of rows i have varies from situation to situation

Comment: I would assume you are looping through some data and at that point, you can identify the row with a simple counter and possible even include this in the button function call, which would then allow the function to be dynamic.

Comment: Sorry, I'd love to write it all out, but I haven't got that much time today.

Comment: I understood what you've said, i'll think about on how i can turn it on code, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the comments said, is tough to work without code. :-)

That said, the general answer is that you want to flag each row in some way so that your onClick script knows which row the button is referring to.

A simple example: each button passes a row number parameter when its onClick is triggered.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This finds the button that was pressed, navigates to the parent `tr` and then finds the first, second, etc. `input` elements and saves them into variables:

```
function fetchGrades(event) {
    var sender = (event && event.target) || (window.event && window.event.srcElement);
    var first = $(sender).closest('tr').find('input:eq(0)').val();     
    var second = $(sender).closest('tr').find('input:eq(1)').val();
    var third = $(sender).closest('tr').find('input:eq(2)').val();
    var fourth = $(sender).closest('tr').find('input:eq(3)').val();
}
```